# Why does this registry reader for Java return nothing?

Tags: java

I'm creating a part of an API for Java which gathers information about your OS (specifically Windows right now). To do this without any external JARs/APIs, I want it to read the registry.

Code:

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class OperatingSystem
{
    String edition;
    String buildBranch;
    String CurrentBuild;
    String productName;
    String release;
    String productID;
    String owner;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        OperatingSystem os = new OperatingSystem();
        os.getWindowsInfo();
        os.returnWindowsBuild();
        os.returnWindowsEdition();
        os.returnWindowsBranch();
        os.returnWindowsRelease();
        os.returnProductID();
        os.returnWindowsOwner();
    }

    public String returnWindowsBuild()
    {
        return CurrentBuild;
    }
    public String returnWindowsEdition()
    {
        return edition;
    }
    public String returnWindowsBranch()
    {
        return buildBranch;
    }
    public String returnWindowsRelease()
    {
        return release;
    }
    public String returnProductID()
    {
        return productID;
    }
    public String returnWindowsOwner()
    {
        return owner;
    }

    public void getWindowsInfo()
    {
        edition = getRegistryValue("\"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\"", "EditionID", "Windows version not detected");
        buildBranch = getRegistryValue("\"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\"", "BuildBranch", "Windows build branch not detected");
        CurrentBuild = getRegistryValue("\"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\"", "CurrentBuildNumber", "Windows build number not detected");
        productName = getRegistryValue("\"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\"", "ProductName", "Windows product name not detected");
        release = getRegistryValue("\"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\"", "ReleaseID", "Windows release not detected");
        productID = getRegistryValue("\"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\"", "ProductID", "Windows product ID not detected");
        owner = getRegistryValue("\"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\"", "RegisteredOwner", "Windows owner not detected");
    }

     public String getRegistryValue(String query, String value, String Fail)
     {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "cmd.exe",
                    "/c",
                    "REG QUERY " + query +  " /v " + value
            );
            Process p = builder.start(); // Query registry
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) // Reads line 2 for output
                r.readLine();
             String result = r.readLine();
             return result;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return Fail; // Returns the third argument in getRegistryValue, in case the operation fails
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run it, it outputs nothing. How would I get it to output the value of the specified registry key?
(This code did work at one point, not sure why it's not working now)

Comment: where exactly is it supposed to output something? show the code where the class is used..

Comment: The main method is where the code is being executed, if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: Where are you having it output anything?

Comment: There is no code here that outputs anything. Unclear why you're surprised.

Comment: How would this code even work before if there was nothing to output? (This is the exact same code of when it did work before)

Comment: @evilarceus That's impossible, as there are no print commands in the code anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap `os.returnWindowsBuild();` with `System.out.print()` if you are looking for some output in console.

Comment: So I was being stupid :L Anyways, thanks for helping me on a simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `System.out.println` calls to output anything.

Update the `main` method to use `System.out.println` to actually output your results (instead of just fetching them and discarding the results). Ie: `System.out.println(os.returnWindowsBuild());`

Comment: His first call after creating the os object, is to getWindowsInfo(). You are correct, though, in that it would be better to put that in the constructor.

Comment: Ah thanks. Missed that with trying to read this all on mobile :)